# I'm trying to redirect to another action from my custom actionfilter attribute but setting the filtercontext.result does nothing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Here's my `OnActionExecuting` method. I checked to see if the condition was satisfied with the `Console.WriteLine` and it was.

**EDIT:**  It seem that setting the context result does not work after i call

user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(context.HttpContext.User);

redirect works when i set context.result before that

```
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All ,Inherited = true)]
public class HasPermissionAttribute: ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private string _permission;
    private AdminDbContext _context;
    private UserManager<AdminUser> _userManager {get;set;}
    private AdminUser user {get;set;}

    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;



    public HasPermissionAttribute(String permission,IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory):base()
    {
        var serviceScope = serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
        _context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AdminDbContext>();
        _userManager = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<AdminUser>>();
        _permission=permission;
        _hostingEnvironment=serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHostingEnvironment>();

    }
    public override async void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {      
    // base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(context.HttpContext.User);
    string webRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;

    if (!HasPermission(_permission)) {  
        Console.WriteLine("condition passed");  
        context.Result = new RedirectToActionResult("UnauthorizedAccess", "UserGroup", null);
    }
   }
}
```

and heres the controller

```
public class UserGroupController : Controller
{

      public UserGroupController(UserManager<AdminUser> userManager,      RoleManager<Role> roleManager, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,AdminDbContext adminDbContext,IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<UserGroupController>();
        _adminDbContext = adminDbContext;
        _roleManager = roleManager;
        _userManager=userManager;
        _httpContextAccessor=httpContextAccessor;

    }

           [TypeFilter(typeof(HasPermissionAttribute),
    Arguments = new object[] { "DELETE" })]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
    {        
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var role = await _roleManager.FindByIdAsync(id.ToString());

        if (role == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(role.ToViewModel());
    }
 }
```

Comment: I don't know if it is because of the dependency injection or async method but I've seen that too. It should redirect once the method `OnActionExecuting` finishes (it just doesn't look like it does that when you step through the code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work for me... (I just left of your authorization logic)

```
public class MyActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        context.Result = new RedirectToActionResult("Index", "Home", null);
    }
}
```

Applied on a controller...

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [MyActionFilter]
    public IActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

The About action now always redirects to the Index action.

Comment: I edited to show my controller, I used a type filter to allow dependency injection. I don't know if that affect the redirection but it still does nothing when i set the result